# How to select records with duplicate column by group using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

For some reason some records have the same ID. Aim is to list all the whole record which have the same ID. For example, how can group the following records by GroupId using LINQ, and find all records with the same ID and list them all? (thus merging all rows in each group into one)

```
var list = new List<Record>()
{ 
    new Record() { GroupId = 0, ValueA = 20, ValueB = 300 },
    new Record() { GroupId = 1, ValueA = 30, ValueB = 700 },
    new Record() { GroupId = 1, ValueA = 40, ValueB = 500 },
    new Record() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 80, ValueB = 300 },
    new Record() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 20, ValueB = 200 },
    new Record() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 20, ValueB = 200 }
};
```

Expect result is the last 5 records.

Comment: Actually you must also mention what is the expectation from values `ValueA` and `ValueB`. Do you want as it is? Or you you want sum of them?

Comment: expect is the whole record that with duplicate ID, i.e.
    new Record() { GroupId = 1, ValueA = 40, ValueB = 500 },
    new Record() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 80, ValueB = 300 },
    new Record() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 20, ValueB = 200 },
    new Record() { GroupId = 2, ValueA = 20, ValueB = 200 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is:

```
var results = (from l in list
        group new {l.ValueA, l.ValueB} by l.GroupId
        into g
        select new {GroupId = g.Key, Values = g.ToList()}).ToList();
```

If you prefer lambda expression, then

```
var results = (list.GroupBy(l => l.GroupId, l => new {l.ValueA, l.ValueB})
        .Select(g => new {GroupId = g.Key, Values = g.ToList()})).ToList();
```

This should give you records based on unique `GroupId`along the other values associated.

**EDIT**

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    foreach (var value in result.Values)
    {
        int valueA = value.ValueA;
        int valueB = value.ValueB;
    }
}
```

I think you are looking for something similar to this.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for "how can group the following records by GroupId using LINQ"

```
var groupList = list.GroupBy((mRecord) => mRecord.GroupId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = list.ToLookup(record => record.GroupId);
var groups1 = groups[1]; //all records with GroupId = 1
```